# django dj-rest-auth custom user registration

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement custom registration using dj-rest-auth library. Unfortunately I'm unable to make custom field of user to save. When i try to register I get null constraint failed on year field. I tried saving it by setting user.year and by setting custom_signup

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
username = serializers.CharField(
    max_length=40,
    min_length=3,
    required=True
)
email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
year = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

def validate_username(self, username):
    username = get_adapter().clean_username(username)
    return username

def validate_email(self, email):
    email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
    if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
        if email and email_address_exists(email):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
    return email

def validate_password1(self, password):
    return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

def validate(self, data):
    if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
    return data

def custom_signup(self, request, user):
    user.year = self.validated_data('year', '')
    user.save(update_fields=['year'])

def get_cleaned_data(self):
    return {
        'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
        'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
        'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
        'year': self.validated_data.get('year', '')
    }

def save(self, request):
    adapter = get_adapter()
    user = adapter.new_user(request)
    self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
    adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
    self.custom_signup(request, user)
    setup_user_email(request, user, [])
    
    return user
```

Comment: Please post the project on github to reproduce

Comment: @Tiana987642 https://github.com/KulSmuf/stackOverflow

Comment: If no one join, I will check it for next few days, currently busy now